# Ferramentas para trabalhar com graficos

Tags: php, html, css

Eu estou precisando buscar dados em um banco e fazer gráficos com ele,acredito que a busca do banco de dados é normal o que muda é a ferramente para fazer o gráfico.
Minha dúvidas são:

-Qual a melhor ferramenta para fazer gráficos?

-Alguém já trabalhou com gráficos e sabe qual o melhor caminho para pesquisar?

-Existe algum pacote para melhorar o visual do gráfico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está trabalhando com php, mas os gráficos poderiam ser exibidos em javascript? Se sim, procura por jquery charts no google.

Comment: Eu estava nessa api mesmo,a documentação é essa né? https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery?hl=pt-br

Comment: Esa documentação é do Google Charts, existem outros, caso tenha dificuldade para entender a documentação, poe no google para aparecer respostas em português, ajuda muito.
Também tem essa, que é muito fácil de usar e muito elegante para o site: http://www.highcharts.com/

Existe uma sessão aqui no stackoverflow para tirar dúvidas sobre o highcharts: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highcharts

Abraços.

Answer (score 4):

Minha sugestão é usar o `d3js` http://d3js.org/

Ele é muito personalizável e a galeria de exemplos é ótima para ajudar no começo https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery